# aerospike installation in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: aerospike

installed aerospike using following commands-

1)wget -O aerospike.tgz 'http://aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu16'

2)tar -xvf aerospike.tgz

3)cd aerospike-server-community-3.15.0.2-ubuntu16.04
 ./asinstall

when executing following cmd-
1)tail -f /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log | grep cake
getting this error-
tail: cannot open '/var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: Seems aerospike server is not running ,thus logs not made
: "ps -ef | grep aerospike" ->

result:

root      7328 30240  0 17:56 pts/0    00:00:00 vi aerospike.conf
root     11304 30240  0 18:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto aerospike
aerospi+ 32519     1  0 16:14 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /opt/aerospike/telemetry/telemetry.py /etc/aerospike/telemetry.conf start --fgdaemon
root     32523     1  5 16:14 ?        00:07:03 /usr/bin/asd --config-file /etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf --fgdaemon
root     32730 30240  0 16:15 pts/0    00:00:00 journalctl -u aerospike -a -o cat -f

Comment: Did you start the service?

Comment: To start the service do: $ sudo service aerospike start

Comment: yes i did start the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 switched from SysInit V to Systemd. On distributions that have switched to SystemD, Aerospike ships config and unit files to match the expectations of Systemd.

To access you logs you will need to use the journalctl command.

Aerospike provides a guide for Systemd here: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/systemd

> Seems aerospike server is not running ,thus logs not made : "ps -ef | grep aerospike" -> result: root 7328

The name of the Aerospike process is asd, so you would need to have run "`ps -ef | grep asd`"